# Hide MainForm when LoginForm is called?

Tags: c#, forms

I have 2 forms, 1 Login form and the other is the Main Application Form.

The Main Form launches Login Form since auth = false, the issue is though since I am calling the login from the main application how do I then hide the main form when the login form is shown and then display the mainform once the user is authenticated?

This is my Main App call:

```
/*
 * Created by SharpDevelop.
 * User: SAVENZ
 * Date: 7/26/2015
 * Time: 3:46 PM
 * 
 * To change this template use Tools | Options | Coding | Edit Standard Headers.
 */
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NewCOCBot
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of MainForm.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            //
            // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
            //
            InitializeComponent();

            //
            // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
            //

            var auth = false;
            if(auth == false){
                LoginForm authForm = new LoginForm();
                authForm.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try this.close() ???

Comment: You could simply use `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`

Comment: @FlatEric that seems to do the trick, what would i need to do to recall or pass the dialog as authenticated? just Close() the dialog?

Comment: `ShowDialog()` returns a `DialogResult`, which you can set in `LoginForm` before you close it.

Comment: Creating login forms is a very traditional newbie-to-winforms mistake.  Such an app always runs in a session where the user already logged-in using the highly secure Windows login procedure.  One that's battle-hardened by being attacked every conceivable way.  You are *not* talking to a complete stranger on the Internet.  Putting your own login procedure on top of that is a very significant security risk, users will simply re-use their Windows logon password and the odds that you treat them just as securely as Windows does are very slim.  Don't do it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to show the login form *before* the main form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MainForm:

```
LoginForm authForm = new LoginForm();
var result = authForm.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // authentication was successful
}
```

In LoginForm: Set authentication result ok (if if was successful)

```
DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

Answer (score 0):

Display the form as a dialog this will hide mainform while login form is visible.

```
LoginForm authForm = new LoginForm();
           authForm.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is run login form and main form both from Program.cs file.

You can change Program.cs file like this:

```
namespace YorNameSpace
{
public static class Program
{
    public static DialogResult result;
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        using (var loginForm = new loading())

         result=loginForm.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // login was successful
            Application.Run(new Main());
        }
    }
}
}
```